# Presenting viewController over another but want it to be transparent

Tags: swift

I am using **self.present** to present a **ViewController**. I want to be able to faintly see what is behind the **ViewController** and can briefly see it but then it goes white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the **ViewController** that presents the second one, you need to add the following in your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
yourPresentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

I assume since you said that you can briefly see the presenting view controller that you have a background with alpha value not set to 1. If not, this is a color I recommend:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.87)
view.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it!